# Indices about cost of living and income in Germany

Tags: germany, salary, cost-of-living

I am searching for cost of living or consumer price index for German cities.
I know Numbeo and others but it doesn't cover all Germany.
And also the average income (disposable or gross).
I hope to find a comprehensive data sets in each; for free or not.

I searched but I couldn't find something covers all the German cities.

Thank you.

Comment: There are something like > 2,000 cities are large towns in Germany.  It is unlikely that there is going to be detailed statistics on all of these, especially for free.  So it would help if you were more specific about which few cities you want details upon.

Comment: It's available for U.S. although it's bigger, so I thought it'll available for Germany, or at least as regions

Comment: The USA is a large country with large differences in Cost of Living.  In Germany many costs are the same or very similar nationwide and don't vary so much.  Tax for example is the same everywhere.  The biggest differences tend to be due to rent (still very popular in Germany) and housing, so you should be able to find data on this comparing many cities, but not all of them.  There are comparisons online about this and cost of living for something like 50 cities, but not 2000, and the underlying data seems to be a paid source.  And most of this is only available in German from what I can see.